# Spring Boot endpoints + webSocket

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket

I'm developing application which has regular endpoints for CRUD operations on entities (I'm injecting controller), the flow of the application should make entities' properties constatly changing so I will be in need to inform front end about those changes in real time. That is why I have registered Web Socket

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

@Override
public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry webSocketHandlerRegistry) {
    webSocketHandlerRegistry.addHandler(new PositionHandler(),"/positions").setAllowedOrigins("*");
}

class PositionHandler extends TextWebSocketHandler {

    private List<WebSocketSession> sessions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
       sessions.add(session);
       while(session.isOpen()){
          HERE I WOULD LIKE TO ACCESS METHOD FOR  CONTROLLER
       }


        super.afterConnectionEstablished(session);
    }

    @Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session, TextMessage message) throws Exception {
       for(WebSocketSession s: sessions){
            session.sendMessage(message);
        }

        super.handleTextMessage(session, message);
    }
}
```

}

inside afterConnectionEstablished I would like to use methods from controller which is injected into ordinary @RestController class. Is there any possibility to do it? And if not how should I refactor.
PS WebSocket works.

Comment: Look up STOMP in spring, you can use a SimpMessagingTemplate in your controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can yous dependency injection in your handler (@Autowired annotation) and invoke method from rest controller. But why you want do this? Do you have business logic inside controller?

Comment: yes, I do have bussiness logic there, should I move it somewhere else?

Comment: Business logic should in general be placed in service layer if you are using 3-Tier (Controller, Service, Repository) architecture... but that is out of the scope of this question. (Moving the logic would neither solve your problem, nor make the example simpler)

Comment: I have Autowired  annotation already inside RestController class, I tried to add it also to the Handler but when connection is established the controller inside handler = null

Comment: Mark your handler class as @Component